# About React Native android Build

Tags: android, react-native, build

I wanna try build
so i did
`react-native run-android`
this one, but, i watched some error about below one.

```
> Task :react-native-community_checkbox:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
46 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 44 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_checkbox:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_checkbox:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/hellograce3/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/hellograce3/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/hellograce3/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_checkbox:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_checkbox:androidJdkImage'. > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/hellograce3/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar. > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/hellograce3/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/hellograce3/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/393400499b2af28f59d755a5f301569b/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules} * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 4s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

how can i do?

my gradle is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

this one

i updated gradle, and removed cash, and reinstalled npm ... i did this one but i can not solve this problem how can i do?